# Typo3 8.7.15 Flexform: displayCond on field pages (record storage page)

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x, flexform

Is there a way to show my flexform field only when a record storage page is defined? I tried the following, but I got an error:

```
   <settings.view.type>
       <TCEforms>
           <displayCond>FIELD:pages:REQ:true</displayCond>
....
```

-> Flex form displayCond on field "settings.view.type" on flex form sheet "sDEF" references a field or field / sheet combination "pages" that might be defined in given data structure but is not found in data values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try prefixing the fieldname with: `parentReq.`

This will then access the parent database record instead of the FlexForm data:

```
<settings.view.type>
    <TCEforms>
        <displayCond>FIELD:parentRec.pages:REQ:true</displayCond>
        ...
    </TCEforms>
</settings.view.type>
```